# Cloud9 IDE with local SSH Workspace - Terminal Window throws execvp(): no such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cloud9-ide

I connected the Cloud9 IDE successfully to my local Ubuntu VM (14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr) and can open the local SSH workspace. When opening the workspace the cloud9 terminal window is flooded with the msg "execvp(3): no such file or directory".

What is going on here and how can I fix it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the working directory you specified for that workspace doesn't exist? That could cause a message like this to appear. If it does exist, please try contacting Cloud9 support (https://c9.io/support).